# Peer-review: Reference to unpublished work

Tags: citations, peer-review, authorship

**Paper I am reviewing**

I am reviewing a paper from authors `Xs`. In their paper, they assume that a function `f` was equal to `g`. In my opinion (see below paragraph), the particular choice of the function `f` can have important impact on the end results. I would note that most people in the field assume that `f` is equal to `g` (without good justification for this assumption).

**Unpublished work from a colleague**

A colleague of mine (let's call him `Y`) had the idea that depending on the field of application the choice of `f` might be important. He worked on it and we recently talked about his first results which suggest that he was right; if `f` equals to `h` for example, the results of interest might differ. He has not published his work yet.

**Issue**

I would like to suggest to authors `Xs` to comment on the potential importance of the `f` they chose. However, by doing so I would give author `Xs` the credit of being the firsts to recognize the importance of the choice of `f` while it is `Y` who first came up with this idea. I obviously want to avoid that. If the work of `Y` were published, I would just suggest `Xs` to cite this work but it is not published.

Should I just remain silent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems highly unethical to disclose the work of Y. If no previous literature questions f=g, I don't see your role as the reviewer to question this. Hold your horses, review this in view of past literature, and wait until the work of Y is public.